# C# object in IronPython: expected interface, got implementation

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

Well, here is a problem:

I have a part of .NET code, translated into IronPython. This code refers to other .NET code (don't ask why). C# method takes c#-written interface as parameter, f.e.

```
public int SomeMethod(ISomeInterface instance)
```

in IronPython I try to call this method from dll, like this:

```
someValue = SharpClass.SomeMethod(self.InheritedProperty)
```

`self.InheritedProperty`has type - implementation of `ISomeInterface`. Let suppose "SomeInterfaceImpl"

And I got runtime error:

`expected ISomeInterface, got SomeInterfaceImpl`

How to avoid this? I cannot do cast  in python, because of abstract interface.

Comment: Does `SomeInterfaceImpl` definitely implement `ISomeInterface`?

Comment: @user9993, yes, but with some implementation tree: SomeInterfaceImpl implements AnotherInterface, that implements ISomeInterface.